# Python while loop in the timer. Cacel didn't take effect, finally quit

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

```
from threading import Timer
import time
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
            format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
            datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
            )
global t #globaljj

class demo_timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__t = None

    def demo_print(self):
        logging.info("hello")

    def demo_start(self):
        if self.__t is not None:
            self.__t.cancel()
            logging.info("timer cancel %s",self.__t)
            self.__t = None
        self.__t = Timer(5,self.demo_print)
        logging.info("timer %s",self.__t)
        self.__t.start()

a = demo_timer()
t = Timer(5,a.demo_print)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    a.demo_start()
```

result:

Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:23] INFO timer <_Timer(Thread-1061, initial)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:20] INFO timer cancel <_Timer(Thread-1061, started 15192)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:23] INFO timer <_Timer(Thread-1062, initial)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:20] INFO timer cancel <_Timer(Thread-1062, started 16088)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:23] INFO timer <_Timer(Thread-1063, initial)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:20] INFO timer cancel <_Timer(Thread-1063, started 14860)>
Thu, 29 Jun 2017 08:55:59 time_test.py[line:23] INFO timer <_Timer(Thread-1064, initial)>

[Done] exited with code=null in 114.895 seconds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question isn't very clear which makes it harder to answer. Try improving it. Here are some resources: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer cancel is taking effect, that is why you are not seeing any "INFO hello" outputs.

Your program does not finish, because your infinite while loop. It cancels the old timer, and then calls demo_start() again, creating a new timer, which is cancelled in the next iteration, and so on.

Comment: Why is it eventually quit?In theory will always run. Why at the time of the 1064th thread exits, whether thread resources are exhausted?

Comment: My understanding is if cancel the Timer, so the corresponding thread resources will be released, this understanding is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it should always run; your IDE or system resource constraints probably stopped it. I believe your understanding is correct and number of threads is unrelated.

Comment: Thank you, indeed is limited in vscode.I was on the basis of printed to judge the Timer thread number attached thread did not release, this understanding should be wrong.